# Spark: RDD Left Outer Join Optimization for Duplicate Keys

Tags: apache-spark, join, rdd

**THE SCENARIO**

I'm trying to write a Spark program that efficiently performs a left outer join between two RDDs. One caveat is that **these RDDs can have duplicate keys**, which apparently causes the whole program to be inefficient.

What I'm trying to achieve is simple:

- Given two RDDs: `rdd1` and `rdd2` (both have the same structure: `(k, v)`)
- Using `rdd1` and `rdd2`, generate another RDD `rdd3` that has the structure: `(k1, v1, List(v2..))`
- `k1` and `v1` come from `rdd1` (same values, this will lead to `rdd1` and `rdd3` have the same length)
- `List(v2..)` is a list whose values are coming from the values of `rdd2`
- To add an `rdd2`'s `v` to the list in `rdd3`'s tuple, its `k` (the key from `rdd2`) should match the `k` from `rdd1`

**MY ATTEMPT**

My approach was to use a left outer join. So, I came up with something like this:

```
rdd1.leftOuterJoin(rdd2).map{case(k, (v1, v2)) => ((k, v1), Array(v2))}
                        .reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
```

This actually produces the result that I'm trying to acheive. But, when I use a huge data, the program becomes very slow.

**AN EXAMPLE**

Just in case my idea is not clear yet, I have the following example:

Given two RDDs that have the following data:

`rdd1`:

```
key | value
-----------
 1  |  a
 1  |  b
 1  |  c
 2  |  a
 2  |  b
 3  |  c
```

`rdd2`:

```
key | value
-----------
 1  |  v
 1  |  w
 1  |  x
 1  |  y
 1  |  z
 2  |  v
 2  |  w
 2  |  x
 3  |  y
 4  |  z
```

The resulting `rdd3` should be

```
key | value | list
------------------------
1   |   a   |  v,w,x,y,z
1   |   b   |  v,w,x,y,z
1   |   c   |  v,w,x,y,z
2   |   a   |  v,w,x
2   |   b   |  v,w,x
3   |   c   |  y
```

Comment: Why not group by key before joining on these keys?

Comment: @TerryDactyl I think grouping would slow down the program even further, am I right?

Comment: I guess it depends on how you generate rdd1 and rdd2. Before trying anything else how are rdd1 and rdd2 partitioned? If you are unfamiliar with spark joins it is definitely worth googling spark sql join optimization. If you can ensure your data is partitioned so that the identical keys are co-located on the same executor then your join will be faster.

Comment: @TerryDactyl That was actually what I wanted to do from the start! I want to have some control on how the tuples are partitioned so the ones with similar keys are at the same place. I did a some search on the Internet but did not find much about the topic.

Comment: I believe colocation is guaranteed if the rdds are partitioned using the same partitioner in the same job.

Comment: @TerryDactyl I didn't change the default partitioner so I guess they should be the same. I think they are not coolocated because of another reason. My program is actually a little bit complicated. The two rdds are generated from the another RDD after filtering and changing keys. I think changing the keys is what causing the issue, what do you think?

Comment: @TerryDactyl I tried your solution by grouping the items in the second rdd, and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't use:

```scala
map { ... => (..., Array(...)) }.reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
```

That's pretty much as inefficient as it gets. To group values like this using RDDs you should really go with `groupByKey`.

Additionally just to `groupByKey` afterwards is pretty wasteful. You are doing the same job  (grouping by key) on the right hand side twice. It makes more sense to use `cogroup` directly (that's how RDD joins work) and `flatMap`

```scala
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, "a"), (1, "b"), (1, "c"), (2, "a"), (2, "b"),(3, "c")
))

val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, "v"), (1, "w"), (1, "x"), (1, "y"), (1, "z"), (2, "v"),
  (2, "w"), (2, "x"), (3, "y"),(4, "z")
))

val rdd = rdd1
  .cogroup(rdd2)
  .flatMapValues { case (left, right) => left.map((_, right)) }
  .map { case (k1, (k2, vs)) => ((k1, k2), vs) }
```

You can also use `DataSet` API which tends to be more efficient in such cases

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list

val df1 = rdd1.toDF("k", "v")
val df2 = rdd2.toDF("k", "v")


df2.groupBy("k")
 .agg(collect_list("v").as("list"))
 .join(rdd1.toDF("k", "v"), Seq("k"), "rightouter")
 .show
```

The result:

```
+---+---------------+---+                 
|  k|           list|  v|
+---+---------------+---+
|  1|[v, w, x, y, z]|  a|
|  1|[v, w, x, y, z]|  b|
|  1|[v, w, x, y, z]|  c|
|  3|            [y]|  c|
|  2|      [v, w, x]|  a|
|  2|      [v, w, x]|  b|
+---+---------------+---+
```

If the intersect of the sets of keys is small you can try to optimize the process by applying a filter first

```scala
val should_keep = {
  val f = df1.stat.bloomFilter("k", df1.count, 0.005)
  udf((x: Any) => f.mightContain(x))
}


df2.where(should_keep($"k")).groupBy("k")
 .agg(collect_list("v").as("list"))
 .join(rdd1.toDF("k", "v"), Seq("k"), "rightouter")
 .show
```

```
+---+---------------+---+
|  k|           list|  v|
+---+---------------+---+
|  1|[v, w, x, y, z]|  a|
|  1|[v, w, x, y, z]|  b|
|  1|[v, w, x, y, z]|  c|
|  3|            [y]|  c|
|  2|      [v, w, x]|  a|
|  2|      [v, w, x]|  b|
+---+---------------+---+
```

When using `Dataset` API please be sure to adjust `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to reflect the amount of data you process.

**Note**:

None of that will help you if number of duplicates in `rdd2` is large. In such case the overall problem formulation is impossible to defend and you should try to reformulate it, taking into account requirements of the downstream process.

Comment: Nice solution! regarding your first comment on using reduceByKey, what I know is that reducing first happens on the same executor and then among them using shuffling. This can greatly help with minimizing the traffic between executors. Whereas groupByKey starts by shuffling and then grouping the items, resulting in a larger number of items being exchanged.

Comment: @m2008m1033m I recommend reading [this](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/04_rdd_actions_and_transformations_by_example.md#be-smart-about-groupbykey).